# Catch emails to all a_user_name@mydomain.com, and execute code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, amazon-ses

In my webapp I have instances where I want to let users send an email to their local representative. But I don't want to expose that user's email so I'd like to have the email sent from a_user_name@mydomain.com, where a_user_name is different depending on who sends it.

Where I'm lost is how to handle the situation where somebody replies to that email, and I need to deliver it to the original author. I'd like to be able to catch that email, look up the user in our database, and send them an email notifying them of the reply. How do I complete this last part?

Using Rails + Amazon SES

Thanks!

Comment: One thing I didn't get is suppose a user `deep@buycott.com` sends an email to the local representative so on which email address he would be sending the email for eg the local representative's email `d_nice@buycott.com`?

Comment: The big question for me: What happens when two users send emails to the same representative? How will you determine which user the representative is replying to? Not in code, in words.

Comment: username's are unique to the User object, so I would want to look the username up in the database, and connect it to the correct User. My question was more along the lines of how do I set up a server that catches all emails to user_names@mydomain.com, and allows me to handle what to do next in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can integrate with a transactional email provider like Mandrill (or others). There's various mandrill rails gems to help.

See: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583197-Inbound-Email-Processing-Overview

The inbound email gets picked up in a controller like:

```
class InboxController < ApplicationController
  include Mandrill::Rails::WebHookProcessor

  def handle_inbound(event_payload)
   #parse event_payload and take appropriate action
  end
end
```

You can then parse that email to get the sender validate it against your user table and pass the message on or whatever.

You probably want to set a subdomain of your domain or a totally separate domain so you can route your normal email traffic to your mydomain.com mailservers and pick up the emails to be parsed by rails / processed by the webhook from mail.mydomain.com or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Base64.encode64](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html)

```
2.0.0-p481 :029 >   encrypted_email=Base64.encode64('mike@gmail.com')
 => "bWlrZUBnbWFpbC5jb20=\n" 
2.0.0-p481 :030 > Base64.decode64(encrypted_email)
 => "mike@gmail.com"
```

OR [MessageEncryptor](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor)

```
2.0.0-p481 :037 >   crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(Rails.configuration.secret_token)
 => #<ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor:0xcd4d6fc @secret="c07692942cde247c96ea3da23a4d6406ebdad7c37f63c13e100731ce03ce24088dbe419da154fb7e504e777c60c7f6f8850d27f8cb8b7968602244ce5c21bfb3", @cipher="aes-256-cbc", @verifier=#<ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier:0xcd4d4e0 @secret="c07692942cde247c96ea3da23a4d6406ebdad7c37f63c13e100731ce03ce24088dbe419da154fb7e504e777c60c7f6f8850d27f8cb8b7968602244ce5c21bfb3", @digest="SHA1", @serializer=ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::NullSerializer>, @serializer=Marshal> 
2.0.0-p481 :038 > encrypted_data = crypt.encrypt_and_sign('mike@gmail.com')
 => "UjF4VFRnRnF1RVJnZXhUUm1KakJZcDFMN1ZoZXVzSmFvLzUwdFkydXNjYz0tLTlsbFI3Vlo4RUNVK2pMZVEzS2tSOWc9PQ==--710d4fcdc202e1b1143e12661d8b40831525f158" 
2.0.0-p481 :039 > decrypted_back = crypt.decrypt_and_verify(encrypted_data)
 => "mike@gmail.com"
```

So.you may use a dedicated table to store both encrypted and original emails and then use it in the FROM section of mail as well as to refer it for future use .So you must use a `Generic` email id that users can use to reply and then you may send this encrypted hidden field which will identify which email id was intended to send and again send to that email.

i know it would be a two way process like:-

1. `Encrypt` email in From part and use **Generic email** where users can reply back
2. Use `hidden field` containing **encrypted** mail
3. So,if the user replies back to the `Generic mail`,check the encrypted mail from `hidden field` and then again **resend** it to the `decrypted` email.

**HOPE THIS HELPS.**

Comment: If you really need confidentiality, you cannot just encode/decode in b64 because anyone could do it.